# Spring Boot 2.6 + Integration - internalPublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor circular dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

We have upgraded to 2.6 Spring boot version.
We are also using Spring's Integration (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration).

When we try to start up the application we get:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  org.springframework.integration.internalPublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
└──<-──┘
```

We were able to repro the issue with a clean Spring boot application:

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnablePublisher;

@EnableIntegration
@EnablePublisher
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
```

Does anyone have a hint of what might go wrong? Maybe some additional configuration is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Has been fixed recently: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3694.

Will be released next week for upcoming Spring Boot `2.6.2`.

As a workaround, instead of `@EnablePublisher` you can add this bean:

```
@Bean(IntegrationContextUtils.PUBLISHER_ANNOTATION_POSTPROCESSOR_NAME)
static PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor publisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {

        @Override
        public void afterPropertiesSet() {

        }

    };
}
```

It's problem that it has that `this.beanFactory.getBean(PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class)` in its `afterPropertiesSet()`. So, to mitigate a cycle we just need to get rid of it!

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the answer!